# why do I receive multiple messages after every message I send in websocket

Tags: javascript, websocket, chat

I am trying to create a chat application and if I send two messages through websocket using my app, I will receive 2 messages from the everyone that sends messages after. If I send another message,  I will then receive three messages from everyone who sends a message to me.

```
chat () {
    const sendMsgDiv = this.shadowRoot.querySelector('.sendMessage')
    sendMsgDiv.classList.remove('removed')
    const submit = this.shadowRoot.querySelector('#submit')
    const input = this.shadowRoot.querySelector('#write')
    input.innerHTML = ''
    input.setAttribute('placeholder', 'Write a message...')
    submit.addEventListener('click', event => {
      event.stopPropagation()
      this.sendMessage(input.value)
      input.value = ''
    })
  }

sendMessage (message) {
    const data = {
      type: 'message',
      data: message,
      username: window.localStorage.getItem('username'),
      channel: 'mychannel'
    }
    const socket = new window.WebSocket('<server_name>', 'mychannel')
    // show the sender message
    socket.onopen = event => {
      socket.send(JSON.stringify(data))
      const message = document.createElement('p')
      message.setAttribute('class', 'senderMessage')
      message.innerHTML = data.username + ' : ' + data.data
      this.shadowRoot.querySelector('.messages').appendChild(message)
    }
    // check if the reciever message is from the same user that sent it
    socket.addEventListener('message', event => {
      const message = JSON.parse(event.data)
      console.log(message)
      if (message.username !== window.localStorage.getItem('username') && message.username !== 'The Server') {
        console.log('message arrived')
        const recieverMessage = document.createElement('p')
        recieverMessage.setAttribute('class', 'recieverMessage')
        recieverMessage.innerHTML = message.username + ' : ' + message.data
        this.shadowRoot.querySelector('.messages').appendChild(recieverMessage)
      }
    })
  }
```

Comment: You don't need to open a new Websocket each time you send a message, just once.

Comment: The JS code snippet at this page: https://javalin.io/tutorials/websocket-example might give you a clue. Also here: https://www.sanwebe.com/2013/05/chat-using-websocket-php-socket. As you can see the WebSocket object is created just once to initialize the connection with the server. After that, it's just a matter of working with the events and the event handlers.

Comment: @KostasX Lifesaver thanks a lot